# SharePoint 2007 - Update all site home pages

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, moss

I am wondering if there is a way to update all site home pages to display a new custom web part.

I have a site collection with 100+ sub sites and I have created a custom web part which i want to display in all site home pages.. what would you suggest as the best way to do this, as as doing this manually will take considerable time?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write the code to programmatically add a webpart to a single homepage.  The specifics of how to do this will vary based on how your homepage is structured, whether it's a publishing page, etc.  It's most likely possible, but implementations could differ.  You'll possibly be using something similar to this:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
using(SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Pagees/Home.aspx"
        , System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

    MyWebPart wp = new MyWebPart();      // your custom webpart
    wp.Title = "My WebPart";

    webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Left", 0);
    webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
}
```

There are lots of variations when searching the subject online.

Once you have that you can create either a console application or a feature to be executed on the top level site, open up each subsite, and then execute the above code.